# Cannot find where JBO-29000 InvocationTarget, msg=null was catched in ADF application

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have an adf application where i use jsff page when i refresh the View Object table which this error:

> "JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTarget, msg=null"

occurs, Here is more detail about it:

[image]

in server log is very limited info i can't seem to track the exception:

[image]

I have tried changing default ADF exception handler(http://adfwebcentermoments.blogspot.com/2015/11/exception-handler-for-adf-application.html) both global and the page(which has the error) to catch this error in java code by placing simple

> System.out.println("Exception is here");

But none invokes those methods to catch the exception.

The thing i want is if i can't fix the exception atleast i can hide it from popping up whenever i go the jsff page.

Anyone knowing to handle this i am really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide whole exception

Comment: Have you provided any EL in the page or any column of VO. Basically when it's coming

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue on a dev/local environnement, set the log level to FINEST and reproduce. It'll tell you which element get you the null

Comment: From where we can check 1227 line number code?

Comment: i made a mistake it correctly is the ViewRowSetImpl class from oracle/jbo/server throw it at line 1227 in adfm.jar

Comment: it also comes from the QueryCollection class from oracle/jbo/server at line 2197 and all 2 class lines i mentioned executes "executeQueryForCollection" which lead to the class ViewObjectImpl also from oracle/jbo/server where the JBO exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

After a while i found the ViewRowSetImpl class from oracle/jbo/server throw it at line 1227 in adfm.jar

it also comes from he QueryCollection class from oracle/jbo/server at line 2197 and all 2 class lines i mentioned executes "executeQueryForCollection" method which lead to the class ViewObjectImpl also from oracle/jbo/server where the JBO exception is thrown.

Comment: This should not be answer. It's comment. Please delete it